# In Kubernetes / AKS how do you direct services to specific node pools' individual nodes. Is there a way for the deployments to choose or is it auto?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-deployment, node-pools

I am new to Kubernetes. One thing I am not sure of is when creating all of these deployments I am starting to max out my cpu/memory usage on my current node pool.

In [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-multiple-node-pools#specify-a-taint-label-or-tag-for-a-node-pool) it states that the SAME configuration of nodes will be created as a "node pool"

> In Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS), nodes of the same configuration are grouped together into node pools.

> System node pools serve the primary purpose of hosting critical system pods such as CoreDNS and tunnelfront. User node pools serve the primary purpose of hosting your application pods.

Also, you can create "taints (lol what)", tags and labels which only seem to "label" per se the node pool. Not an individual node.

> When creating a node pool, you can add taints, labels, or tags to that node pool. When you add a taint, label, or tag, all nodes within that node pool also get that taint, label, or tag.

So with all of that said, it doesn't seem like the control is inside of a node pool's node. So how does it work for nodes in a node pool when deploying workloads and services?

Do I need to worry about managing that or is that automatically managed and pods are created across the plane of nodes in a node pool. I'm not really seeing the documentation for this.

One more thing, "[Vertical Pod Autoscaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/vertical-pod-autoscaler)"

This seems like a good option but doesn't really explain in the documentation what is going on in terms of the nodes in a node pool. Except for this one statement at the end.

> This article showed you how to automatically scale resource utilization, such as CPU and memory, of cluster nodes to match application requirements.

The question about the vertical auto scaler (which is really vertical + horizontal (IMHO)) but I understand the reference/verbiage, is what happens if you aren't using this? Do you have to manage each deployment on your own? How do deployments distribute over the individual node pool plane?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but is infrastructure-related, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Read this https://blog.kubecost.com/blog/kubernetes-taints/. I am not 100% sure but AKS is not the same as EKS(Aws),regarding allocation node resourceas and deployments.